# Inconsistent error ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: oracle

I got an error with the message "ORA-01722: invalid number" when I executed my query. As digged in, I found out, I will get that error when I use a numeric value for a column that expects a `varchar`.
In my case my query had a case statement like

```
CASE WHEN CHAR_COLUMN= 1 THEN 'SOME VALUE' END
```

But the behavior was different in different instances of same oracle version. The same query worked in one of our dev oracle server, but not in the other. I am curious if there is any configuration that allows oracle to use numeric value to be used in a character column.

***PS:*** The oracle version that we are using is ***Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production***

Comment: It it possible that both servers just have different data, and your dev server does not have any row with non-numeric strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [reproduce the issue](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f54c8/1):

```
create table foo (
  CHAR_COLUMN varchar2(10)
);
create table bar (
  CHAR_COLUMN varchar2(10)
);
insert into foo (CHAR_COLUMN) values ('1');
insert into foo (CHAR_COLUMN) values ('2');
insert into bar (CHAR_COLUMN) values ('1');
insert into bar (CHAR_COLUMN) values ('yellow');
```

Then, when querying against numeric `1`, the first query table works and the second doesn't:

```
select * from foo where CHAR_COLUMN = 1;
select * from bar where CHAR_COLUMN = 1;
```

When you ask Oracle to resolve this comparison:

```
WHEN CHAR_COLUMN = 1
```

... Oracle converts the query internally to:

```
WHEN TO_NUMBER(CHAR_COLUMN) = 1
```

In my example, this can be spotted in the explain plan:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |    1 |     7 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
| * 1 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | FOO  |    1 |     7 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 1 - filter(TO_NUMBER("CHAR_COLUMN")=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I never rely on [implicit data type conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm) but always make it explicit:

```
CASE WHEN CHAR_COLUMN = TO_CHAR(1) THEN 'SOME VALUE' END
```

Or even not convert at all:

```
CASE WHEN CHAR_COLUMN = '1' THEN 'SOME VALUE' END
```

The reason is that Oracle tends to convert the character string to a number, not the other way round. See the example from the linked manual page:

> **Text Literal Example**
>
> The text literal '10' has data type CHAR. Oracle implicitly converts it to the NUMBER data type if it appears in a numeric expression as in the following statement:
>
> ```
> SELECT salary + '10'
>   FROM employees;
> ```